How to add after-erroring logic on ? and returning Result
Scenario:
The codebase generally uses Result<X, E> for return types.
As we know, ? effectively converts into a return Err(e) when used.
But, I have some telemetry information that needs to be emitted on error. Essentially, I am constructing a stack trace for debugging.
Slightly pseudocode example:
fn f()->Result<X, E> { ... } 

fn g(ctx: &mut Context) -> Result<Y, E> {
  match f()  {
    Ok(x) => Ok(x.to_y()),
    Err(e) => { 
       ctx.log(e); 
       return e
    }
}

I would like to be able to essentially run a standard hook on error-exit, so I could use the ? operator, but also gather the error rationale in the telemetry system.
I believe this corresponds to an after advice or after-throwing advice in aspect oriented programming approaches.
What's the usual practice here to shrink the boilerplate?

You can put this before ? https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/result/enum.Result.html#method.inspect_err

@drewtato - "    #[stable(feature = "result_option_inspect", since = "1.76.0")]" new functions all the time. That might be the way.

If you want this only in some cases:
Add inspect_err() or map_err() (if you need to change the error):
fn f() -> Result<X, E> {
    // ...
}

fn g(ctx: &mut Context) -> Result<Y, E> {
    Ok(f().inspect_err(|e| ctx.log(e))?.to_y())
}

If you want this on all (or many) errors:
Create a custom error type. There is a hook you can use to customize the behavior of the ? operator: if invokes From::from() to convert the error. You can log there:
pub struct LogError<E>(pub E);

impl From<E> for LogError<E> {
    fn from(err: E) -> Self {
        ctx.log(&err);
        Self(err)
    }
}

fn f() -> Result<X, E> {
    // ...
}

fn g(ctx: &mut Context) -> Result<Y, LogError<E>> {
    Ok(f()?.to_y())
}

You can't use this method to log an error when it is already a LogError, but you can use a backtrace or context to do that.
This also has the drawback that existing conversions to other error types won't work: you will need to use explicit into().

If I understand what you're saying, the ctx variable in g will be propagated to the from call? That is surprising to me.

@PaulNathan No, it won't. You will need to make it global variable or find another way to pass it.

If you have only a few return positions, then you can use inspect_err to log the error:
fn f() -> Result<X, E> { todo!() }

fn g (ctx: &mut Context) -> Result<Y, E> {
    Ok (f().inspect_err (|e| ctx.log (e))?.to_y())
}

If your g function contains a lot of ? places and you don't want to add inspect_err to all of them, you can use an inner closure and only inspect its return value:
fn f1() -> Result<(), E> { todo!() }
fn f2() -> Result<(), E> { todo!() }
fn f3() -> Result<(), E> { todo!() }
fn f4() -> Result<X, E> { todo!() }

fn g (ctx: &mut Context) -> Result<Y, E> {
    Ok ((|| -> Result<Y, E> {
        f1()?;
        f2()?;
        f3()?;
        Ok (f4()?.to_y())
    })
    .inspect_err (|e| ctx.log (e)))
}

